# Android Java ZipFile / ZipEntry "Malformed" in some cases?

Tags: java, android, zip

Unfortunately I can't reproduce this on my end, it is just being reported via by crash analytics. It seems to be "rare"-ish, but happens enough to warrant attention.

The code is simply opening a ZIP file and iterating through the files inside:

```
try
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        zipFile = new ZipFile(tempZipFile, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")); // Fixed crash on later Android versions, when a file in the ZIP has a special character
    else
        zipFile = new ZipFile(tempZipFile);
}
catch (IOException e)
{...}

// Read entries in ZIP file.
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

while (entries.hasMoreElements() == true)
{
    ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement(); // <--- Crash occurs here
    // ...
}
```

And the crash:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED[1]
       at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:65)
       at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toStringUTF8(ZipCoder.java:120)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:592)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile.-wrap2()
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.next(ZipFile.java:552)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:527)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:526)
       at package.extractFromZIP(AndroidLauncher.java:1078)
```

Seems 64% of crashes are Android 9, 28% Android 8, so that "if" statement with the charset defined doesn't seem to be the issue.

If I had to guess, I'd still say its a charset / "weird" character in the filenames causing the problem. Is there some charset to use (for example, above I am using Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1") for Android 9+) that would cover, basically, any filename. The app is localized in many languages across many countries, from Japan to Russia to the USA, so any character is possible.

Unless that's not the issue? Problem is the crash report isn't giving much info other than "malformed", hoping someone here has maybe encountered it before?

Comment: Wait, [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) doesn't cover ěščřňůť... all common in Czech ([ISO-8859-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2)). This is why we're lucky to have UTF-8 nowadays.

Comment: `I am using Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1") for Android 9+) that would cover, basically, any filename.` Android N = SDK 24 = Android 7.0. As far as I can see it crashes on Android 7+ *because* of your special case, which doesn't handle any characters outside of a legacy Western Europe encoding.